# Permanently add to emacs load path

Tags: emacs

I am trying to add "~/" to the emacs load path, because for whatever reason it is not there.  I managed to find the command for adding to the emacs load path:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/")
```

When I execute this command the load-path variable contains all the stuff it did before, and "~/" is added to the list.  The problem is when I quit emacs, the next time it starts the "~/" had been removed from the list, the change is not persistent.  How do I add something to the emacs load-path variable permanently?

Adding to the .emacs file won't work here, because the problem is that the .emacs file, which is in the ~/ directory, is not being loaded, so modifying the .emacs file won't fix this problem.

Comment: In Emacs type `C-h v user-init-file RET`. That tells you the path/name of the file it's trying to load at start-up. It might not be where you think it is (especially if you're using Windows?).

Answer (score 3):

I guess there is a typo in phils' comment. The right way should be C-h v user-init-file RET. Maybe you customized this variable in some other places and you forgot. Try changing the value of this variable back to the default.

Comment: Ah, yes, that was an unfortunate typo. I've deleted that comment and replaced it with the correct version.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. I haven't customised the variable anywhere that I know of.